# Difference between using Access.Application object vs. a database connection

Tags: database, excel, vba, ms-access, object

I've been scouring for information on how to add and query data within Excel VBA from an ACCDB. I've come across many answers: OpenDatabase() from my coworker, database connections and using an Access.Application object. What I couldn't figure out is, is there a benefit to using the Access object instead of creating a connection to a database with a string and such? I did read that using the Access Application object I didn't need to have the Access engine on the computer running the VBA, and I opted to do this for that reason. Plus, it looked a lot simpler than using a connection string and going that route. I've implemented the Access Object and it worked like a charm. So my question is, what's the benefit or disadvantage to doing the Access Object way vs. doing it another way? Thanks all!

Comment: I would go with DAO rather than an application object. DAO is much faster with MS Access. An application object just uses up memory for no good reason. DAO is pretty nearly as easy as an application object.

Comment: You have you ideas a little round the wrong way. If you use a connections string or DAO, you do not need a full version of MS Access, if you use an application object, you are running a full version. It can lead to problems when code is set to run when the application is opened as well as only working when MS Access is installed.

Comment: So, DAO is faster, easy, and uses less memory than an app object and does not require the application. An object can use functions. Here's my task: I import CSV (or cleaned XLSX) files into an ACCDB, import separate data into a different table, query the data and export another XLSX that I play with. What sounds better for this task? The database isn't very big now but it will get bigger by about 10k records/week.

Comment: I wouldn't use an application object for something like this. DAO is a better choice although both of them could be made to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the 10k incremental addition to the DB or your CSV input is increasing by 10K?

If it's the former then yes, storing it in a database is a good idea and I would use the DAO route. You notice that not many people are fans of firing up the Access application, mainly because you're not really using Ms Access features (it's more than a data store).

As an alternative, skip Excel and put your macro inside Access, since you have the app. There are a lot of goodies in Access that you can take advantage of.

However, if your CSV is always at full volume, you may just want to process the data yourself within Excel/VBA. I assume that the "other" table is a reference table.